# Assistance writing a mysql query based on conditions

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to write a MySQL statement based on an if statement.

Here's what I want to do: I need the query to collect rows based on whether or not an item is going to be due within two weeks or if it's already passed due.

This is what I have so far:

```
select
  t_id,
  firstName, 
  lastName, 
  checkTime,
  due
from (checkOut join People)
where checkOut.p_id = People.p_id
order by due IF(DATE(NOW()-checkOut.due) <= 2 WEEK);
```

MySQL is stating that there is a syntax error near the IF statement (I'm not surprised as I'm not familiar with writing conditional statements in MySQL).

Another question is regarding whether or not MySQL will yield a date that is negative (i.e. to indicate that an item is passed due). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to select both `passed due` and `not passed due` ?

Comment: Yes. My goal is to select values that will be due within two weeks as well as those that are passed due. It sounds odd, but it makes sense in the way I am using it.

Answer (score 1):

The `IF` cannot be used as you have it.  A portable alternative is to place a `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` to assign a `0` where the condition matches, and `1` which sorts after `0` when it doesn't.

```
select
  t_id,
  firstName, 
  lastName, 
  checkTime,
  due
from 
  checkOut 
  join People ON checkOut.p_id = People.p_id
order by 
  /* Use DATE_SUB() */
  /* This will sort those not yet past due ahead of those already past due. 
     If this is the opposite of what you want, switch the 0 and 1 */
  CASE WHEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK) <= checkOut.due THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

Note that I have converted your implicit join into an explicit one by changing the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause.

Comment: What is the reasoning for the on clause? It's a very basic question, but I am new to MySQL. It has been working well without the ON in a different variation of this query.

Comment: @user1675246 Without the `ON` clause, you get a cartesian product of the two tables. If the relationship is one to many, for example, you would end up with far more rows than intended. Even if it works without it, it is _highly_ recommended to explicitly include the join condition.

Comment: @user1675246 Sorry - I just noticed you had the join condition in your WHERE clause. That is a strange mix of implicit joining and explicit (via `JOIN` keyword) It is preferred practice to use the `JOIN` syntax as I have it above.

Comment: I see what your saying; I'll change it then.

Comment: It seems to work, but I had to remove the order by to do so. Thanks.

Comment: @user1675246 I thought you said you _wanted_ to return all of them, but to sort those past due differently. Do you only want the rows which are past due or not yet due?

Comment: Sorry about that. I was rather vague in that regard. What I really mean that I want only the entries within 2 weeks of being due to those that are after due - not necessarily all entries in the table. Regardless, I modified it, and it works well. Thanks.

Comment: @user1675246 So do you still need help with this or have you solved it with your modification?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this,

```
SELECT t_id, 
       firstname, 
       lastname, 
       checktime, 
       due 
FROM   checkout 
       JOIN people 
         ON checkout.p_id = people.p_id 
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN ( Now() - INTERVAL 2 week ) <= checkout.due THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
          END, 
          due
```

Comment: I believe that is the answer I'm looking for. In this case, can a "negative" date be obtained and MySQL will interpret it as less than checkout.due?

Comment: There is not `negetive` date concept.

Comment: Figured so. In that case, how will MySQL handle that event?

Comment: With date arithmetic. See this condition `( Now() - INTERVAL 2 week ) <= checkout.due`.